# making sqlcmd self-contained so it would be possible to run without installation, for CentOs

Tags: linux, bash, centos, portability, sql

I am trying to make a bash script to connect to remote SQL server with sqlcmd

in the devp machine, as I have admin privileges, runs smoothly

but I NEED (and capitals because it is imperative) to build the functionality without packages installation because it needs to runon very limited machines

I upload de executable (/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd) from devp machine, download on test machine and try to run with ./sqlcmd

```
sqlcmd: error while loading shared libraries: libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

so I try to do the same with the dependant library (/usr/lib64/libodbc.so.2.0.0) but error keep the same

I guess, that libraries should be installed and are not found placed on the same directory that the executable ...

**any way to go?**

I read about [how to run a software in linux without installing it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179505/how-to-run-a-software-in-linux-without-installing-it) but not sure I understand it all, probably too complex for me.

Comment: You need to have the software installed properly on the target system. For something like `sqlcmd` there will be many non-trivial dependencies

Comment: yes, this I know, I SHOULD have the software installed, BUT HARD REQQUIREMENTS, we must do it without any installation, otherwise, need to look for other solutions

Comment: Do you need to trust the output from `sqlcmd`? Install it properly. Use a Change Request to have the software installed, if necessary. Otherwise, as you say, you'll need to look for other solutions

Comment: Are you familiar with $LD_LIBRARY_PATH?  That’s an env variable used in these kinds of situations

Comment: @roaima, I do not understand what you mean by "seed to trust the output" , you mean matter of impersonation and so on?

Comment: If you don't install it properly, can you have confidence in the output that it gives you?